# Reduction to $n\log n$ time problem

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

If a problem $A$ is poly-time reducible to a problem $B$ ($A <_\mathrm{p} B$), and $B$ can be solved in time $O(n\log n)$, can $A$ also be solved in time $O(n\log n)$?

Comment: Inside of P you need weaker reductions than poly-time many-one, which effectively allow you to solve $A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't guarantee that $A$ can also be solved in time $O(n\log n)$ because the reduction from $A$ to $B$ might require more time than that (for example, $n^3$ steps).

Comment: Indeed, one can take $A$ to be in $\mathrm{TIME}(n^2)\setminus\mathrm{TIME}(n\log n)$, say, and $B$ to be some non-trivial language decidable in time $O(n\log n)$. In that case $A$ polytime reduces to $B$, but provably $A$ cannot be solved as fast as $B$.